# How can I disable the type indication in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml

Consider this function here, how can I disable the auto generated grey text showing the type scheme of the function?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [OCaml Platform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform) page:

> ### Disable code lens
>
> Code lens are type information displayed over a symbol. In the
> screenshot below, code lens is grey text t -> Sandbox.t.
>
> [image]
>
> You can disable code lens for all extensions, i.e., in whole VS Code,
> set this settings in your settings.json:
>
> ```
> "editor.codeLens": false
> ```
>
> Or if you only want to disable it
> for OCaml:
>
> ```
> "[ocaml]": {  "editor.codeLens": false }
> ```